# Why my copyright paragraph disappears whenever it's sibling is a h3 with a class 'hidden'?

Tags: html, css, browser, delay

I have a strange situation in which sometimes upon making changes to css code in sublime text 2, saving it and previewing locally in google chrome, the changes are not immedietaly visible. Sometimes it takes time for them to 'apply' in browser.

For example I had a frustrating situation a moment ago where my copyright paragraph was not being displayed whenever a neighbouring h3 with a class of 'hidden' was in the same container. I've commented for a moment the h3, the copyright paragraph appeared and then by curiosity I've uncommented back the h3 with a class 'hidden'. I was expecting the paragraph to disappear but it stayed like nothing would happen. What's going on here ? Why browser is not showing the exact results upon code changes ? Why at first the paragraph was disappearing and now it's not doing that ?

Here's the part of code I was editing :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvyrI

Comment: Clear internet history or use private browsing

Comment: there is nothing special, your copyright paragraph should always show (appear). The `h3` does nothing, in fact it's clipped to an empty rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better solution to dynamically preview the entered changes in sublime text 2 ? Some sort of plugin maybe ?

Comment: Off topic, but the font you specify is not available on every system (it's actually pretty rare), so you may want to consider uploading it to your site and using a font-face definition.

Comment: Thanks for advice ! Actually, it is being loaded from google fonts resource and if it fails then a first possible sans-serif, arial, verdana font is being loaded.

Comment: You should change the font order.  Always make sans-serif the last option because the browser will always load it.